# How to filter based on elements in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter, javascript-objects

I have the following multiple arrays as follows:

```
//Condition one
var categorys = [1, 2];

//useType = 0,Return useType=0 element

//useType = 1,Returns the same categorys element as c_id

var data = [
  {c_id:0, name:'phone', useType:0},
  {c_id:1, name: "milk", useType:1},
  {c_id:2, name: "apple", useType:1},
  {c_id:3, name: "orang", useType:1},
  {c_id:4, name: "red", useType:1}         
]
```

I made the following attempt:

```
let result = data.filter((item, index) => {
  if(item.useType === 0) {
    return true
  } else if(item.useType === 1 && item.c_id === categorys[index]){
    return true
  }
  else {
    return false
  }
});
```

I want to get the following results

```
[
  {c_id:0, name:'phone',useType:0},
  {c_id:1, name: "milk",useType:1},
  {c_id:2, name: "apple",useType:1}
]
```

But I can only get one

```
[
  {c_id:0, name:'phone',useType:0},
]
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to check whether the `categories` array contains a specific `c_id` value:

```js
const categories = [1, 2];

const data = [
  {c_id: 0, name: "phone", useType: 0},
  {c_id: 1, name: "milk", useType: 1},
  {c_id: 2, name: "apple", useType: 1},
  {c_id: 3, name: "orang", useType: 1},
  {c_id: 4, name: "red", useType: 1}         
];

const result = data.filter(({useType, c_id}) =>
    useType === 0 || useType === 1 && categories.includes(c_id));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.filter()` and `.includes()` methods to get the desired output:

```js
const categorys = [1, 2];

const data = [
  {c_id:0, name:'phone',useType:0},
  {c_id:1, name: "milk",useType:1},
  {c_id:2, name: "apple",useType:1},
  {c_id:3, name: "orang",useType:1},
  {c_id:4, name: "red",useType:1}         
];

const result = data.filter(
  ({ c_id, useType }) => ((useType == 0) || (useType == 1 && categorys.includes(c_id)))
);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I am surprised by this way of writing.

Comment: `c_id == 0` should be `useType == 0` according to the logic outlined in the question.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Thanks for the input. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `includes`:

```
let result = data.filter((item,index)=>{
    if(item.useType === 0){
       return true
    }else if(item.useType === 1 && categorys.includes(item.c_id)){
        return true
    }
    else{
       return false
    }
});
```

But to avoid iterations on the categories array, you can make it an object like this, making it more performant:

```js
var categories = {
  "1": true,
  "2": true
};

var data = [
  {c_id:0, name:'phone',useType:0},
  {c_id:1, name: "milk",useType:1},
  {c_id:2, name: "apple",useType:1},
  {c_id:3, name: "orang",useType:1},
  {c_id:4, name: "red",useType:1}         
]

let result = data.filter((item,index)=>{
    if(item.useType === 0){
       return true
    }
    
    if(item.useType === 1 && categories[item.c_id] === true){
        return true
    }
    
    return false
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer,This is a good method and advice